# SELECT semelhante ao "INNER JOIN" célula a célula do registro?

Tags: mysql

Tenho pouco conhecimento sobre SQL e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um SELECT no mesmo registro (linha), e para cada valor de célula trazer o registro correspondente de uma segunda tabela. Algo semelhante ao INNER JOIN, eu acredito.

Exemplo:
O usuário digita uma busca em "Tabela de Tarefas"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para cada valor de célula é feito uma busca na segunda tabela: "Tabela de Operações".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

BUSCA 9003. Ficaria o retorno:

15 - Descrição 3 | Local 3
35 - Descrição 7 | Local 7
30 - Descrição 6 | Local 6
10 - Descrição 2 | Local 2
5  - Descrição 1 | Local 1
20 - Descrição 4 | Local 4

Enfim, eu iria pegar num LIST em Java. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: já pensou em trocar a modelagem? E se uma tarefa precisar de 7 operações, como fica ?

Comment: Sim, foi me sigerido isso mesmo. Porém sei que não passa de 6 operações por enquanto. Como isso vem de um excel e agora estou remodelando para mysql, provisóriamente queria fazer isso para o programa continuar rodando. Se isso for uma tarefa simples né..

Comment: acho que remodelar essa situação é mais simples que ficar fazendo 6 subqueries toda vez que precisar rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa estrutura você teria que fazer um join com um `OR` para cada campo da tabela `tarefas` para retornar o resultado esperado, eu faria de outra maneira, uma tabela n:n de tarefas e operações para caso de um dia ter outra tarefa não precisar dar manutenção no código. porém para atender sua necessidade do momento a `query` ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
    o.* 
FROM operacoes o
INNER JOIN tarefas t
ON (t.op1 = o.codigo)
OR (t.op2 = o.codigo)
OR (t.op3 = o.codigo)
OR (t.op4 = o.codigo)
OR (t.op5 = o.codigo)
OR (t.op6 = o.codigo)
WHERE t.codigo = 9003;
```

Dessa maneira outra criei todas as tabelas em uma estrutura um pouco diferente, que eu acho que seria mais viável para você com uma tabela n:n como comentei acima, assim você não teria problema de adicionar mais operações a uma tarefas, segue os exemplos:

```
CREATE TABLE tarefas_new(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    codigo INT
);

CREATE TABLE operacoes_new(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  codigo INT,
    descricao VARCHAR(255),
    `local` VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE `tarefas_has_operacoes_new` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_tarefa` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_operacao` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_tarefas` (`id_tarefa`),
  KEY `fk_operacoes` (`id_operacao`)
);

INSERT INTO tarefas_new VALUES(1,9001),(2,9002),(3,9003),(4,9004);
INSERT INTO operacoes_new VALUES(1,5,'Descricao 1','Local 1'),(2,10,'Descricao 2','Local 2'),(3,15,'Descricao 3','Local 3'),(4,20,'Descricao 4','Local 4'),(5,25,'Descricao 5','Local 5'),(6,30,'Descricao 6','Local 6'),
(7,35,'Descricao 7','Local 7');
INSERT INTO tarefas_has_operacoes_new VALUES(2,3,7),(3,3,6),(4,3,2),(5,3,1),(6,3,4);

SELECT
    o.*
FROM tarefas_new t
INNER JOIN tarefas_has_operacoes_new tho
ON tho.id_tarefa = t.id
INNER JOIN operacoes_new o
ON tho.id_operacao = o.id
WHERE t.codigo = 9003;
```

Comment: Obrigado arllondias. Funcionou perfeito para o que preciso no momento. Me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Por nada! @rafB